# find element in array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to return the object that contains the value (any letter matching in any object) in search field.

I want to return the object that the array inside an array of object matches.

Example:

if

> search = 'dog'

then I want to return

> [{name: Jake, last: DK, tags: ['fun','dog','cat']}]

Or if

> search = 'a' return [{name: Jake, last: DK, tags: ['fun','dog','cat']},{name: John, last: Hop, tags: ['boring','mouse','trap']}]

My attempt:

```
this.state = {
search = '',
arr = [{name: Jake, last: DK, tags: ['fun','dog','cat']},
       {name: John, last: Hop, tags: ['boring','mouse','trap']}]
}
//asuming the arr is stored in state
let filteredTag = this.state.arr.filter(obj => {
      if (obj.tags !== undefined) {
      return (
        obj.tags.filter(tag => {
          return tag.includes(this.state.search)
        })
      )
      }
    })
```

Also, I have

> if (obj.tags !== undefined) {

because its a list that appears on click of a button and its undefined initially when page render.

Comment: `.filter()` always returns an array. And an array is [_truthy_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Hence `filteredTag` (which btw. is a terrible name when the actual content is an array of students) will always have all students (when `student.tags` is not `undefined`).

Comment: Even after your last edit, you still refer to `student` without, as far as anyone can see, having defined it.  (And also mention it in your second code fragment.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger sorry I've just fixed all the typo's. I had originally copy pasted my code but was making it easier to read, but didn't notice all the typos.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of filter should be true/false depending on whether you want the particular element.With that in mind,you need to make following changes.

```
let filteredTag = this.state.arr.filter(obj => {
  if (obj.tags !== undefined) {
  return (
    obj.tags.filter(tag => {
      return tag.includes(this.state.tagSearch)
    }).length > 0 // since if tag has any element matching,filtered tags length can be checked
  )
  }
  return false // since in undefined case,search condition is not met.
})
```

Comment: Follow up question, what if I wanted to also filter by first name or last name?

Comment: I assume you want the search item to be present in any of the following.

1.Included in tag of the tag list.
2.Included in the firstName
3.Included in the lastName.

Add LGGICAL OR conditions with inner filter.


     obj.tags.filter(tag => {
      return tag.includes(this.state.tagSearch)
    }).length > 0 || obj.name.includes(this.state.tagSearch) || obj.last.includes(this.state.tagSearch)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `true` or `false` in the callback function of `filter`. For example, `student.tags.filter(` has a correct callback function since it returns either true or false. However, `this.state.arr.filter(obj => {` does not return a boolean. Here's how it should be changed:

```
//asuming the arr is stored in state
let filteredTag = this.state.arr.filter(obj => {
    if (obj.tags === undefined) return false;
    var result = student.tags.filter(tag => {
       return tag.includes(this.state.tagSearch)
    });
    return result.length > 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find all objects that have tags that "match" the search term (a match is defined as `tag.includes(term)`):

```js
function search(term, arr) {
  return (arr || []).filter(e => (e.tags || []).some(t => t.includes(term)));
}

var data = [{
    name: 'Jake',
    last: 'DK',
    tags: ['fun', 'dog', 'cat']
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    last: 'Hop',
    tags: ['boring', 'mouse', 'trap']
  }
];

console.log(search('dog', data));
console.log(search('a', data));
console.log(search('dog', undefined));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple if you just wanted to find the whole term. Since you want to find partial terms as well, you need to look at each tag. `some()` is really useful for that because you can set a condition and it reuturns a boolean, which is what you need here:

```js
let arr = [{name: 'Jake', last: 'DK', tags: ['fun','dog','cat']},
           {name: 'John', last: 'Hop', tags: ['boring','mouse','trap']}]

let term = 'dog'
let found = arr.filter(item => 
  /* return a boolean here */
  /* && will short circuit returning false if there's no tags */
  /* some will return true if any word contains term */
  item.tags && item.tags.some(word => word.includes(term))
)
console.log(found)

// also works with `a`

term = 'a'
found = arr.filter(item => 
  item.tags && item.tags.some(word => word.includes(term))
)
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

in this method, you return many elements that have the same tag:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Jake', last: 'DK', tags: ['fun','dog','cat']},
           {name: 'John', last: 'Hop', tags: ['boring','mouse','trap']},
   {name: 'Demian', last: 'Bibiano', tags: ['dog','cat','trap']}];

function search(searchText){
 var ret = [] 
 arr.forEach(function (element){ 
  if(element.tags.includes(searchText)){
   ret.push(element)
        }
 })
 return ret;
}

console.log(search("dog"));
```